# How can I check the amount of lamports sent to in an anchor function?

Tags: anchor, rust

Assume that I have the below program and I want to restrict the caller of `hello` function pay at least X number of lamports to be able to call it.

```
declare_id!("some-id");

#[program]
mod hello_world {
    use super::*;

    pub fn hello(ctx: Context<Hello>) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Hello {}
```

As far as I'm familiar with anchor, I think I have to set constraints on `Hello` account. But I don't know how to set such constraint for amount of the receiving transaction which is invoking our function.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to enforce a "fee" to execute the instruction would be to add a simple system program transfer to it, like the following:

```
system_program::transfer(
        CpiContext::new(
            ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
            system_program::Transfer {
                from: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
                to: ctx.accounts.receiver.to_account_info(),
            },
        ),
        fee,
    )?;
```

This will not stop someone from calling the instruction persay, but will require that they pay the fee for the instruction to be executed successfully.

For example: you want to force someone to pay 10 lamports to log "Hello!"

```
declare_id!("some-id");

#[program]
mod hello_world {
    use super::*;

    pub fn hello(ctx: Context<Hello>) -> Result<()> {
    
        system_program::transfer(
          CpiContext::new(
            ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
              system_program::Transfer {
                from: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
                to: ctx.accounts.receiver.to_account_info(),
              },
           ),
          10,
        )?;

        msg!("Hello!");
    
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Hello {
   #[account(mut)]
   pub receiver: Account<'info, (some account struct)> (or AccountInfo<'info>)
   #[account(mut)]
   pub payer: Signer<'info>,
   pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

If you want to get closer to the desired effect, you can encapsulate the core logic of the program in a separate utility function, and have the execution of that function be contingent on the transfer occurring.

Answer (score 3):

You're not actually making a constraint specifying the lamport transfer, so much as you are telling your instruction to send the lamports from one account to another.

Your `Hello` context will require that you specify the sender of the lamports (as a *Signer*) and a receiver of the lamports. Both will need a `mut` constraint since we are modifying them. You'll also need to include the `system_program` which will handle the transfer. Here's an example:

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use solana_program::system_instruction;
// ...

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Hello<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub from: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub to: AccountInfo<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}


pub fn hello(ctx: Context<Hello>, amount: u64) -> Result<()> {
    let from_account = &ctx.accounts.from;
    let to_account = &ctx.accounts.to;

    // Create the transfer instruction
    let transfer_instruction = system_instruction::transfer(from_account.key, to_account.key, amount);

    // Invoke the transfer instruction
    anchor_lang::solana_program::program::invoke_signed(
        &transfer_instruction,
        &[
            from_account.to_account_info(),
            to_account.clone(),
            ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
        ],
        &[],
    )?;

    Ok(())
}
```

Here's a [guide](https://www.quicknode.com/guides/solana-development/anchor/transfer-tokens) that walks through SOL and Token transfers that could be help.

Answer (score 3):

The answers above are correct, but you dont need to use this invoke instructions.
Anchor is a beautiful framework that came to help us.
Below is an example of cpi transfer.

A transfer cpi without signer seeds:

```
    let accounts = Transfer {
        from: self.from.to_account_info(),
        to: self.to.to_account_info()
    };

    let ctx = CpiContext::new(
        self.system_program.to_account_info(),
        accounts
    );

    transfer(ctx, fee)
    }
```

make sure you import:

```
  use anchor_lang::{prelude::*, system_program::{Transfer, transfer}};
```

When you are importing this, Under the hood the transfer will do that invoke instruction for you:

```
pub fn transfer<'info>(
ctx: CpiContext<'_, '_, '_, 'info, Transfer<'info>>,
lamports: u64,
 ) -> Result<()> {
let ix = crate::solana_program::system_instruction::transfer(
    ctx.accounts.from.key,
    ctx.accounts.to.key,
    lamports,
);
crate::solana_program::program::invoke_signed(
    &ix,
    &[ctx.accounts.from, ctx.accounts.to],
    ctx.signer_seeds,
)
.map_err(Into::into)
}
```

I believe that your code will become significantly cleaner and more understandable.

Have a great day.

Comment: I don't want a way to transfer SOL, I need to check how much SOL the caller of my instruction is paying to my instruction.

Comment: As you can see on of the arguments of the transfer cpi is lamports.
"pub fn transfer<'info>(ctx: CpiContext<'_, '_, '_, 'info, Transfer<'info>>, lamports: u64)"

This lamports is the amount that the caller will pay to call your instruction. You can define this anywhere, directly on the function, or in a struct.
Think about this like, in order to call your instruction the user will have to make a deposit(your fee). 
This will fix your issue " function pay at least X number of lamports to be able to call it."